# How to parse XML into JSON via jasmine

Tags: xml, json, jasmine

i have a question

i have made unittests and my results go into a xml file

what i want is a parser ,so that i can parse the data from XML into JSON via jasmine and put them in my database

my question now is :

Does anybody knows how to do this or has somebody already done this and would like to teach me?

Comment: Jasmine has no such utility. How are you generating your XML file? Are you using a test runner like Karma or JSTestDriver?

Comment: i use : jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(
        'outputdir/', true, true));

i am using protractor to run my tests